If the mgf if finite in a neighborhood of zero then there's $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\varepsilon \Vert X\Vert }]<\infty $
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma ,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a random variable. If the moment generating function $M_X(s)=\int _{\Omega} e^{\langle s,X(\omega )\rangle }d\mathbb{P}(\omega )$ of $X$ is finite in a neighborhood of 0, can we conclude that there's $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\varepsilon \Vert X\Vert }]<\infty $? Here $\Vert \cdot \Vert $ denotes the Euclidean norm.

I know that this is true if $n=1$.
According to the Lemma 1.16 of the book "Statistical Decision Theory" (written by Liese and Miescke), that proposition is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^\times $. The proof of that lemma basically says that to prove that proposition you need to use the following inequalities: $e^{|x|}\leq e^{-x}+e^{x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\Vert X(\omega )\Vert \leq \Sigma _{i=1}^n|\langle e_i,X(\omega )\rangle |$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$ with $(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$ denoting the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Trying to use theses inequalities I got
$
\mathbb{E}[e^{\varepsilon \Vert X\Vert }]=\int _\Omega e^{\varepsilon \Vert X(\omega )\Vert }d\mathbb{P}(\omega )\leq \int _\Omega \Pi _{i=1}^ne^{\varepsilon |\langle e_i,X(\omega )\rangle |}d\mathbb{P}(\omega )\leq 
$
$\int _\Omega \Pi _{i=1}^n(e^{-\varepsilon \langle e_i,X(\omega )\rangle }+e^{\varepsilon \langle e_i,X(\omega )\rangle })d\mathbb{P}(\omega )=\int _\Omega \Pi _{i=1}^n(e^{\langle -\varepsilon e_i,X(\omega )\rangle }+e^{\langle \varepsilon e_i,X(\omega )\rangle })d\mathbb{P}(\omega )$.
But I don't know if the last term is finite if $M_X(\pm \varepsilon e_i)<\infty $ for all $i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$.

Thank you for your attention!

What happens if you multiply out the product in your last integral and and use bilinearity of the inner product?
